# trying to compare elements of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in php and i am using the array_intersect function to find the common elements and if common elements exist but the issue is there are two common elements but i am getting only one element here is my code...

```
function check_if_exists($company_timings,$in_time) {   
    $length_of_company=sizeof($company_timings);
    $length_of_emp=sizeof($in_time);
    for ($i=0; $i <=$length_of_company-1 ; $i++) { 
        # code...
        for ($j=0; $j <=$length_of_emp-1; $j++) { 
            # code...
            if ($in_time[$j]==$company_timings[$i]) {
                # code...
                $common[]=$company_timings[$i];
                return $common;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: because your function returns as soon as the first common element is found (btw i don't see any use of array_intersect)

Comment: i want to return it when all the common elements are found how should i do that

Comment: don't return before the loops have completed

Comment: print the $common after the complete execution of for loop.

Comment: after the execution of first loop @AfshanShujat

Comment: @iqra why aren't you using `array_intersect()`?

Comment: after the execution of outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
function check_if_exists($company_timings,$in_time) {   
    $length_of_company=sizeof($company_timings);
    $length_of_emp=sizeof($in_time);

    for ($i=0; $i <=$length_of_company-1 ; $i++) { 
        # code...
        for ($j=0; $j <=$length_of_emp-1; $j++) { 
            # code...
            if ($in_time[$j]==$company_timings[$i]) {
                # code...
                $common[]=$company_timings[$i];
            }
        }
     }
     if(count($common) > 0){
         return $common;
     }else{
         // Return else;
     }
 }
```

OR short way:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);

-- Output --
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Comment: the issue is i want to return them within the if block if condition is met other wise i want to return something else is there a way to achieve that

Comment: Code updated. Check now and let me know if it still doesn't fit into your requirement. BTW why have you not mentioned this thing in your original post? Always try to be as much descriptive as much you can to get quick response.

Comment: sir i have another issue in the same code can u plz help me in figuring out the solution to that problem

Comment: Please post another question by referring this question.

Answer (score 1):

return common array after the loop ends as you are returning data inside the loop that's why loop breaks...

```
function check_if_exists($company_timings,$in_time)
{  
    $length_of_company=sizeof($company_timings);
    $length_of_emp=sizeof($in_time);

    $common= array();// empty array..
    for ($i=0; $i <=$length_of_company-1 ; $i++) { 
        # code...
        for ($j=0; $j <=$length_of_emp-1; $j++) { 
            # code...
            if ($in_time[$j]==$company_timings[$i]) {
                # code...
                $common[]=$company_timings[$i];
            }
        }
     }
     return $common; //return common values..

}
```