# comparing two array to find common elements and then finding the indexes of those common elements in first array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in php named as `company_timings` and `in_time`, respectively.

I have found the common elements in both the arrays and stored those common elements in common array.

Now I want to find the indexes of these common elements in the first array, i.e in `company_timing`.

Below is my code:

```
$length_of_company=sizeof($company_timings);
$length_of_emp=sizeof($in_time);
for ($i=0; $i <=$length_of_company-1; $i++) { 
    # code...
    for ($j=0; $j<=$length_of_emp-1; $j++) { 
        # code...
        if ($in_time[$j]==$company_timings[$i]) {
            # code...
            $common[]=$company_timings[$i];
    }
}
}
```

All the three arrays look like these

```
$company_timings=array('09:00:00','10:00:00'.'11:00:00','12:00:00');
$in_time=array('09:00:00','11:00:00');
$common=array('09:00:00','11:00:00');
```

Now I tried passing `$common` in `array_search` func to find the indexes of 09:00:00 and 11:00:00 respectively in `$company_timings`

```
    $indexes=array_search($common,$company_timings);
```

but I didn't get anything but when I used

```
   $indexes=array_search("11:00:00",$company_timings);
```

I got the desired outcome which is 12...

Can you guys tell me how should I achieve that?

Comment: Please show us both arrays.

Comment: You need to show what these two array looks like. Also, show your expected result array.

Comment: `array_intersect` returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved. ??

Comment: @u_mulder plz see the updated question

Comment: @ObjectManipulator plz see the updated question

Comment: @RamRaider that is not my question i have already found the common elements

Comment: @iqra but your question is to find the indexes of common elements in the first array, and `array_interesect()` returns the indexes that you're asking for. This has already been suggested to you in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143051/trying-to-compare-elements-of-two-arrays), but you seem to be ignoring it

Comment: @billyonecan ok sir let me try that

Comment: also, in your example array you're concatenating (`'10:00:00'.'11:00:00'`) instead of adding separate entries (`'10:00:00', '11:00:00'`)

Comment: @billyonecan thankew sir it worked i was so naive trying to achieve that using loops thankx alot

Comment: @RamRaider i apologize i dint pay attention to your answer before ur answer worked for me thankx alot

Comment: @billyonecan that was typo sir

Comment: @billyonecan sir now i am having the result as array([0]=>09:00:00,[2]=>11:00:00);how to get the keys...i want to store the keys in another array

Comment: [`$whatYouWant = array_keys($common)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: @billyonecan thanxk alot